# AWS CLI Getting Error: Unable to load paramfile, but file exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

What I have done is created an S3 Bucket and uploaded the a .json file that I want to run an EMR cluster that will search the .json (terminology may be wrong here)

However, when I try to run this from CLI I get an error stating:

```
Error parsing parameter '--steps': 
Unable to load paramfile file://xxxx/xxxx.json: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxxxx/xxxxx.json'
```

I obviously have replaced my real .json with 'xxx' location but it does exist there when I check on the front-end.

Here is the outline of what I am trying to run:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "XXXXXXXXXXXX" --ec2-attributes 
SubnetId=subnet-XXXXXXXX --release-label emr-5.4.0 --auto-terminate -
-log-uri s3://XXXXXXXXXXX/ --use-default-roles --enable-debugging --instance-groups 
InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=c4.large 
InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=3,InstanceType=c4.large 
--steps file://xxxxxx.json
```

I have also tried plugging in the URL to the .json in place of the `file://` and that also did not work.

Comment: Have you tried the format that the example shows? `--steps file://./multiplefiles.json`
It is in example 18 in [create-cluster](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html)

Comment: @SteveG Seems to have fixed it. Thank you my friend, total overlook on my end!